# A button in an ng-repeat that is changing 10 times per second causes it not to be clickable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

#### Description

I have part of a web page that shows each teams name and score and it has two buttons for each team (Score -1, and Score +1). [image]

Teams is an array and the teams are shown using an ng-repeat.

```
    <!-- Teams Info & Control -->
    <div class="row center-text" style="height: 40%;">
      <div class="col" ng-repeat="team in game.teams">
        <h5 style="display: inline;">{{team.name}}</h5>
        <i class="fa fa-edit" ng-click="editTeamName($index)" class="btn btn-link"></i>
        <h6>{{team.score}}</h6>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <button type="button" ng-click="scoreChange($index, -1)" class="btn btn-primary fill-height fill-width">Score -1</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <button type="button" ng-click="scoreChange($index, 1)" class="btn btn-primary fill-height fill-width">Score +1</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The teams array is part of a larger object called "game" this object is received 10 times per second from a socket.io server. It needs to be 10 times per second because there is a timer in the game object that needs to be displayed to the user with high accuracy.

How the game object is updated on the client side:

```
socket.on('gameUpdate', function(game) {
  $scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.game = game
  });
});
```

Sample game object:

```
{
  gameRunning: false,
  shotClockTime: defaultFullShotClock, //Value changing 10 times per second other values may change too but not as frequently
  oldShotClockValue: defaultFullShotClock,
  teams: [{
    name: "White",
    score: 0
  }, {
    name: "Blue",
    score: 0
  }],
  inOvertime: false,
  currentPeriod: 0,
  periods: {
    mainGame: generateMainGame(defaultPeriodTime, defaultBreakTime, defaultHalfTime),
    overtime: generateOverTime(defaultOverTimePeriodTime, defaultBreakTime)
  }
}
```

#### What I believe to be the problem

When the game object changes, the teams display HTML is updated ($$!) even though no changes have been made to the teams array itself. The problem is that a mouse-down then mouse-up event usually takes longer than 0.1 seconds meaning that they will not happen to the same button so they are not registered as a click meaning that the ng-click is not called.

$$! (I think this is happening because in inspect element that section is flashing purple. Also, the button color, when hovered over, is rapidly alternating between the hover and default colors. [Video](http://rfsite.tk/flashing.mp4))

#### Possible solutions

1. Make angular-js realize nothing has changed and consequently it won't change the HTML meaning everything will be fine (IDK how to do this but if you do then this could be a solution)
2. Have the buttons stay constant as they never change depending on what the teams array is (unless it gets bigger meaning there are more of them)
3. Don't use ng-repeat copy and paste the code because there should always be two teams (This is a last resort solution because I may need to add more teams in the future and its "bad" code)

Comment: even if its wont solves youre problem you should update $scope props only when something did changed.
so you can compare props before assigning them to the scope properties.

Comment: if you can post your controller code so we can make see how the data is updated and also why 10 times per second ?

Comment: have you tried using track by in your ng-repeat?

Comment: @GoorLavi I have to update the property because teams is an array that is part of a larger object (game) in which another part has changed

Comment: @DaMightyMouse I made edits to the post to answer your questions

Comment: @bryan60 I added "track by $index" and my program now works. Could you submit an answer explaining why this works and what "track by $index" does (I don't really understand it) so that I can give you the credit?

Comment: added an answer and some explanation, and recommend a minor change to your code if possible

Comment: Thank you for your answer and help I'll upvote it once I reach 15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the track by clause in your ng-repeat like:

```
<div class="col" ng-repeat="team in game.teams track by $index">
```

Track by is a useful clause that does a few things, but one of them is that it lets angular track which items are in a list so that it knows which ones need to be rerendered or which already exist.  However, if these items are from database and have a unique identifier, it's actually better to use that property as the tracker rather than the index as it performs better and allows for reordering:

```
<div class="col" ng-repeat="team in game.teams track by team.id">
```

docs:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat